# How to use .htaccess with exclusions

Tags: htaccess

I want all requests on a domain to be redirected to `https`, with the exception of just one particular file. I'm not sure how to accomplish this with .htaccess

```
-bash-3.2# cat .htaccess
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
-bash-3.2#
```

The above code redirects everything perfectly, however, I need the `robots.txt` file to be accessible via `http://` vs the `https://` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !robots\.txt
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com/$0 [R,L]
```

Note that `HTTPS` is a more reliable indicator of whether or not SSL is enabled.

Answer (score -1):

This would fit better in serverfault but...

You can work with a pre-condition first. Something like:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http:// www.domain.com

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} http://(www)?\.domain\.tld\/robots\.txt
RewriteRule http://domain\.tld\/robots\.txt [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:// www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: -1 ... have never seen the protocol and domain name included in the `%{REQUEST_URI}` environment variable...

Comment: This was just a detail. The focus should be the idea of pre-condition. Nice reply yours by the way, much more elegant.